# sed pattern match between two strings; 2nd pattern fails

Tags: regex, sed

I was trying to extract a pattern between two strings. In the example below, I want my output to be only "mydata.data":

```
> echo "this/cluster/data/mydata.data?x-username=me" | sed 's/.*data\/\(.*\)?x/\1/'
> mydata.data-username=me
```

What do I need to do so that the string after the 2nd match ("-username=me") is not output?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `.*` at the end of the pattern to consume all the rest of the line. Also, it is recommended to use delimiters other than `/` if you have `/` in the pattern.

Use

```
echo "this/cluster/data/mydata.data?x-username=me" | sed 's,.*data/\(.*\)?x.*,\1,'
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/JWSE41588)

The pattern will match

- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `data/` - a literal substing
- `\(.*\)` - capture into Group 1 (`\1`) any 0+ chars
- `?x` - match `?x` literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars to the rest of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern doesn't match the rest of the line, so it passes through.  Change ?x to ?x.* and the \1 will replace the rest of the line.

The right half replaces everything that matches the left half, so your pattern has to match everything you want to replace.

Comment: ah, I see! Thanks!!